# JvmOverloads annotation for class primary constructor

Tags: constructor, annotations, kotlin

Why is it prohibited to autogenerate many constructors visible to Java from class primary constructor with default params likes this?

```
@JvmOverloads
class Video(private val id: Long, val ownerId: Long, var title: String? = null, var imgLink: String? = null, var videoLink: String? = null,
        var description: String? = null, var created: Date? = null, var accessKey: String? = null, var duration: Long? = null,
        var views: Long? = null, var comments: Long? = null) : Entity
```

> This annotation is not applicable to target 'class'

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It's not prohibited, you are just applying `@JvmOverloads` to the wrong target. The proper way to annotate primary constructor is to explicitly specify `constructor` keyword with `@JvmOverloads` before:

```
class Video @JvmOverloads constructor(
    private val id: Long,
    val ownerId: Long,
    var title: String? = null,
    var imgLink: String? = null,
    var videoLink: String? = null,
    var description: String? = null,
    var created: Date? = null,
    var accessKey: String? = null,
    var duration: Long? = null,
    var views: Long? = null,
    var comments: Long? = null
) : Entity
```

Comment: beware: it looks like there's some bug in @JvmOverloads. When I use it on custom Views then Instant Run fails, however when I define the constructors myself it works

Comment: And remember to put parameter(s) without default value at the beginning  (like it is on above example). Without this @JvmOverloads doesn't work.

Comment: @antygravity 3 medium articles on `@JvmOverloads` failed to mention that `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.