# Hiding view default constructors

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there a way in Kotlin to hide (place somewhere else) the default constructors of a view? Maybe creating a subview or extension or something similar.

Currently all my views look like this, which is a little verbose:

```
class MyView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int): View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int): this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?): this(context, attrs, 0, 0)
    constructor(context: Context): this(context, null, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [default arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#default-arguments):

```
class MyView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0, defStyleRes: Int = 0): View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
```

In case you need to invoke these constructors from Java, consider [applying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748906/jvmoverloads-annotation-for-class-primary-constructor) the [`@JvmOverloads`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-overloads/index.html) annotation to the constructor:

```
class MyView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0, defStyleRes: Int = 0): View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
```

Comment: Don't know how I forgot about that. Thanks!

Comment: Could you updated your answer with: class MyView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0, defStyleRes: Int = 0): View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)? With that its working when using the view from xml.

Comment: the formatting is a bit odd. I think this is a good case for splitting the constructor into a multiline

Comment: @voddan this syntax is not the same as having the constructor inside the class. This still lets you use init{} inside the class

Comment: @Heinrisch see my answer

Answer (score 1):

More or less proper formatting for the @udalov's answer:

```
class MyView(context: Context, 
             attrs: AttributeSet? = null, 
             defStyleAttr: Int = 0, 
             defStyleRes: Int = 0) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
```

or

```
class MyView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, 
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null, 
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0, 
        defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
    // ....
}
```